# ios in app purchase consumable pucducts design guildline question

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a question about in-app purchase design.

You can earn points by paying for consumable products in app.
With that point, you can purchase digital content and use it for 3 days.

I wonder if the above design is an issue with In-app Purchase Guidelines.

thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the above , actually this is the logic of consumble products , you are not limited to a duration ( 3 days even 1 hr ) , if you provide an acceptable service to the user then you're free for any time limit , a common example is increasing game lives